# How to Generalizing batch call on list in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, coding-style, java-8

I have following repeated code.

1. Give a list, other api parameters and max item supported in list.
2. Divide list in sub partions.
3. For each partition call api with given parameters.

So I have following repeated code for each api:

```
final List<List<GivenType>> partions = Lists.partition(givenListObject, batchSize);
final Iterator<List<GivenType>> iter = partions.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    final APIResponse response = this.performSingleBatch(iter.next(),
            /* ... , arguments which need to be passed, argument count can differ
            from api to api, ...*/
     );

    //Some custom processing with response object

    if (iter.hasNext()) {
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    }
}
```

I was thinking to use callable. to reduce this repeated code. So I will have a function:
performBatchRequest(callable,requestType,requestList,batchSize,timeToSleep)

So my code will look like: {Not 100% java syntax}

```
public void batchProcess(callable, GivenType, givenListObject, batchSize, sleepTime)
    final List<List<GivenType>> partions = Lists.partition(givenListObject, batchSize);
    final Iterator<List<GivenType>> iter = partions.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        callable.call();
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        }
    }
```

A consumer can use it by:

```
batchProcess((list)-> {
 //Specific logic
}, GivenType, givenListObject, batchSize, sleepTime )
```

I have following question:

1. How do I pass back current partition of list?
2. Is it worth to avoid this code repetition ?
3. Do you see problem with purposed solution?
4. Any suggestion to improve purposed solution?

Comment: Perhaps executors are better for this than rolling your own.

Comment: Since all the code repetition is basically your manual loop code, you might start using the for-each loop which has been introduced in Java 5. Besides that, I don’t see a *solution* which we can discuss. It’s not even clear what the problem is…

Comment: @Holge Using for each loop there is no easy way to know if iteration is last. I don't want to sleep in last iteration. 

Main problem is to avoid duplication of code of splitting the string and Thread.sleep after each iteration.

Comment: @Vivek Goel: but there is an easy way to know whether you are in the *first* iteration. So you can simply `sleep` at the beginning of the loop’s body it it is not the first iteration. However, relying on `sleep` is an indicator for bad design anyway.

Comment: @Holger sorry to change context. Can you please add more info about "relying on sleep" is and bad design? My function currently throws InterruptedException.

Comment: Because `sleep` is just a placeholder for what you actually want to achieve. What do you want to achieve? I don’t know, as neither the code nor your question tells me. If I knew what the purpose is, I suggested alternatives. But in 99% of all cases, there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @Holger I want to avoid bombarding service calls and keep a delay between each call.